# Hide breadcrumb only on 404 page

Tags: css, drupal-7

I created a custom node for 404 page and added the path /node/83 to the site information. And new node is applied. I can't hide (display:none) .breadcrumb to apply to it.  I'm trying to do it through css injector and have it apply to only the 404 page.  I'm checking it with inspect element and it works and there is only .breadcrumb and i don't see any additional classes that looks like page-404. I added new rule to CSS injector and I don't know what is the path to apply it only to 404 page: 
[path to not found page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fvqE.png)

or another idea is to use class that is only applies for 404 page, if there is any by default:
[add a class to not found page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGKB9.png)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can add a new class for the particular section and can configure display: none for the same.

Comment: That is what I don't understand How to add class to page 404, it's not like home page or any other node.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide it in CSS but avoid sending the breadcrumb to the browser.

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260304/prevent-path-based-breadcrumb-in-theme-or-dont-show-breadcrumbs-for-403-404-r

Answer (score -1):

This is drupal so Im not to sure if you can do a php check to see if its a 404 page or even if the 404 page has a css class on the body tag if so i would go that way (inspect the element if you can see a class on body that references an error page just target the breadcrumb that way eg, body.error .breadcrumbs {display: none;} if this is not possible take a look at this 
https://www.drupal.org/node/15366

Basically this tells you how to make your own 404 page.

- Create two nodes, one for each kind of page error (403 and 404).
- Determine the ID number of the node you wish to redirect users to. One way to determine the node's ID number is to visit the node and look at the number after the last slash in your browser's address bar. This is your node's ID number.
- Now enter the paths to your nodes in the appropriate boxes on your error reporting settings page. For example, if the node ID number for 403 error codes is "83," you would type "node/83" into the "Default 403 (access denied) page" setting.
- Drupal 6 mysite.com/admin/settings/error-reporting
- Drupal 7 mysite.com/admin/config/system/site-information
  Because you are creating nodes, they will show up in the tracker and popular content blocks and anywhere else real nodes would be display. If this isn't acceptable, there is a contributed module called Custom Error that avoids this problem.

  Also consider the Drupal 7 contributed module, Redirect 403 to User Login. Which provides redirection to the login page and configurable 403 and 404 error messages.

***EDIT***

Ok go to sites/all/themes/themename/template.php and edit this file.

add this to the top

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
 // Adds a Custom 404 page
 $header = drupal_get_http_header("status");
 if($header == "404 Not Found") { ?>
   <style>
    .your-custom-css-here {}
   </style>

 <?php }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't explain it right. The custom node is applying to 404 page like you are saying I added the path in "site information". Only thing I can't find a way to do is hiding  breadcrumb or hide a menu links, just as an example on this page. If I add a path node/83 to CSS injector breadcrumb style is applying but only for exactly that page  not on 404 page.

Answer (score -1):

Open the 404 page where you'd like to add the CSS rule. Open [web inspector](https://thewc.co/articles/view/web-inspector-tutorial) and look on the body or html tag for a class that is specific to the page. Something like `page-404`

Then in your custom CSS add

```
.page-404 .breadcrumb {

    // Your styles

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Already checked any class that looks anything like that in html code.  I read that there is a a consistent class (such as "section-404") added to your <body>, which you can then style with global css via css injector. If I create a custom 404 node and set it via Configuration > Site information. I didn't find. Maybe there is another name...